# Questions on SE Android app's Feed only show 1 tag

Tags: bug, tags, android-app, android-app-feed

SE Android App Version: 1.0.84

In Feed section, the questions are showing with its first tag only, even though it's having more than one tags for the post.

Note: In few cases, the Feed section showing with more than one tags, but most of the time with one tag only.

I have recorded the issue, showing the Feed section and navigate to its correspondence post.

[image: First tag only visible in the Feed Section]

Comment: Same issue on the full hot questions list.